# Cross out a transition of automaton

Tags: tikz-pgf, automation

I have the following automaton.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, >=stealth', auto, node distance=0.5cm and 1.5cm, semithick, initial text=]
  \node[state, initial] (q0) {$q_{0}$};
  \node[state] (q1) [above right = of q0] {$q_{1}$};
  \node[state] (q2) [below right = of q0] {$q_{2}$};

  \path[->, shorten >=1pt]
  (q0) edge node {$a$} (q1)
  (q0) edge [dashed] node {$a$} (q2)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And I want to cross out one transition, so it will look something like this.

[image]

How do I add one bold red cross on the middle of the transition?

Comment: You can add the `calc` library and: `\draw[red,thick] ($(q0)!0.5!(q2)$) ++  (45:0.2) --++ (225:0.4);
  \draw[red,thick] ($(q0)!0.5!(q2)$) ++ (135:0.2) --++ (315:0.4);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got multiple ways to add something to a path/straight line (apart from figuring out where that point is manually).

As you know, you can add a node (like those `$a$`s) along an edge.

You could just use a node with a red X, i.e.

```
\tikz\path[->, shorten >=1pt] (q0) edge node {$a$} (q1)
  edge [dashed] node {$a$}
    node[red, marking, sloped] {\Huge$\times$} (q2);
```

I've set up the key `marking` so that it is the same as `auto = false` since you don't want that node to be put to the left or right of the line.

You can also use the `cross out` shape of the `shapes.misc` library where you can control the size of the cross by manipulating the size of the node with the usual means: `inner xsep`, `inner ysep`, `minimum width`, `minimum height`.

```
\tikz\path[->, shorten >=1pt] (q0) edge node {$a$} (q1)
  edge [dashed] node {$a$}
    node[cross out, draw=red, marking, sloped, solid,
         shorten >=0pt, inner ysep=.5em] {} (q2);
```

Or, with maybe a bit more control from the user-interface side of things, a `pic` that draws that cross manually. Here, I've set up a pic named `cross` that takes one optional argument that specifies (half) the length of the lines and uses the value of the key `cross angle` to tighten that angle of that cross.

```
\tikz\path[->, shorten >=1pt] (q0) edge node {$a$} (q1)
  edge [dashed] node {$a$}
    pic[red, marking, sloped, cross angle=10] {cross} (q2);
```

Since you're using `shorten >` and `->` for the path with the edges these get passed down to the nodes and pics which is why I've had to add a few counter-corrections on these.

---

In your actual document, you best put all this in a nice style like

```
\tikzset{
  Cross/.style={
    sloped, auto=false, shorten >=+0pt, shorten >=+0pt, arrows=-, solid, …}}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows.meta, shapes.misc}
\tikzset{
  marking/.style={auto=false},
  cross angle/.initial=0,
  cross/.pic={\draw[solid, arrows=-, shorten <=+0pt, shorten >=+0pt]
                   (225+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cross angle}:{#1})
                 --( 45+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cross angle}:{#1})
                   (135-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cross angle}:{#1})
                 --(315-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cross angle}:{#1});},
  pics/cross/.default=2.5mm}
\tikzset{% just for this answer
  every picture/.append style={
    >=Stealth, auto, node distance=0.5cm and 1.5cm, semithick, initial text=},
  every picture/.append code={
    \node[state, initial] (q0) {$q_{0}$};
    \node[state] (q1) [above right = of q0] {$q_{1}$};
    \node[state] (q2) [below right = of q0] {$q_{2}$};}}
\begin{document}
\tikz\path[->, shorten >=1pt] (q0) edge node {$a$} (q1)
  edge [dashed] node {$a$}
    node[red, marking, sloped] {\Huge$\times$} (q2);

\tikz\path[->, shorten >=1pt] (q0) edge node {$a$} (q1)
  edge [dashed] node {$a$}
    node[cross out, draw=red, marking, sloped, solid,
         shorten >=0pt, inner ysep=.5em] {} (q2);

\tikz\path[->, shorten >=1pt] (q0) edge node {$a$} (q1)
  edge [dashed] node {$a$}
    pic[red, marking, sloped, cross angle=10] {cross} (q2);
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This works very well, thank you!